# How to center align text produced by numpy.savetxt?

Tags: python, numpy, alignment, center

I use a little wrapper around [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to automatically produce header names and create somewhat intelligent width alignment for a readable output. A more barebones solution is at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1545190/467522).

I want to know how to specify a width and have the output text aligned to the center, and not just left justified as indicated in the docs.

From the `numpy.savetxt` docs, I see this info:

> ```
> Notes
> -----
> Further explanation of the `fmt` parameter
> (``%[flag]width[.precision]specifier``):
> ```

```
flags:
    ``-`` : left justify

    ``+`` : Forces to preceed result with + or -.

    ``0`` : Left pad the number with zeros instead of space (see width).

width:
    Minimum number of characters to be printed. The value is not truncated
    if it has more characters.
```

The docs point to a more 'exhaustive resource' at the [python mini format specification](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), but the information there is incompatible for alignment information.

> The meaning of the various alignment options is as follows:

```
Option  Meaning
'<'     Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this is the default for most objects).
'>'     Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space (this is the default for numbers).
'='     Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the digits. This is used for printing fields in the form ‘+000000120’. This alignment option is only valid for numeric types.
'^'     Forces the field to be centered within the available space.
```

The incompatibility is because savetxt does not accept `'^'` as a valid formatting character. Can anybody throw some light on how to specify the format in `numpy.savetxt' so that the output is center-aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine more complex format options including the centered `'^'` flag using `format`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,3))*100
a[1,1]=111.12321
a[2,2]=1
np.savetxt('tmp.txt',a, fmt='{:*^10}'.format('%f'))
```

Giving:

```
****100.000000**** ****100.000000**** ****100.000000****
****100.000000**** ****111.123210**** ****100.000000****
****100.000000**** ****100.000000**** ****1.000000****
```

Comment: Your inclusion of `****` confused me for a bit. I checked it though, and it does answer my question. Thank you. I use finally `fmt='{0: ^{1}}'.format(fmtname, fieldlen)` where `fmtname` is one of the accepted format specifications for `np.savetxt`.

Comment: Yeah, I just used this to depict the centralizing effect... Thank you!